# Allow all group members to create directories and files

Tags: permissions, users, group, chmod, privileges

There are 2 users

```
sftp_user  
apache
```

Both users belong to the `updaters` group as well as other groups.

New directories and files are created in the `/updates/` directory.

```
drwxrwsr-x 8 sftp updaters 4096 Feb 27 16:12 updates
```

The `/updates` directory has the sticky bit set to the `updaters` group.

```
chmod g+s /updates
```

In this scenario, sftp can create new directories and files using SFTP.  However, when apache tries to create new directories and files, permission is declined.

How can I make it so both users (in the group `updaters`) can create new directories and files?

Comment: Why would there be a downvote?  Could you at least add a comment before just downvoting?  Doesn't give any opportunity to learn why this question would be downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

The permissions on the `updates` directory are not quite right for what you are looking to do.  In order for the apache user to be able to write new files to the updates directory, they need the write permission.  In this case, as apache is a member of the `updaters` group, just use `chmod g+w /updates` to allow any user from the updaters group to create new directories and files.

If you'd like the subdirectories to default to the same group assigned to `/path/to/updates`, (rather than the primary group-id of the folder's creator), use `chmod g+s` as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182225/106159).

Comment: Thanks.  Updated the /updates directory permissions for group write.  New directories created by apache user have apache:updaters ownership.  How can I apply this to subdirectories as subdirectories are owned by apache:apache (which is apache's primary group)

Answer (score -1):

Use command `newgrp` to switch to apache's supplementary group `updaters`.