# EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value

Tags: filesystems, mount

I.e. I want the permissions to be 1000, so I can rsync to it without needing sudo.

I tried `sudo mount -o nofail,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1` but that fails with `EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value`.

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/432160/676 you cannot use `uid=1000,gid=1000`... why? A later thread suggest running `sudo chmod g+s -R /mnt/sda1/`. Is this really the right approach to get my drive mounted as 1000 instead of "nobody"??

Comment: The ext4 filesystem supports file ownership/permissions natively.  You can set the ownership/permissions on the directory to which you're trying to sync to whatever values you want.

Comment: Use `sudo chown 1000:1000 /mnt/sda1/whatever` to change ownerships, add option `-R` to do this recursively (`chmod g+s` is really [something else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182212)).

Comment: @hendry I understand your bewilderment. In order to mount a non UNIX-like filesystem (e.g., FAT32) with a certain user, we have a simpler syntax—just a `uid` option—than when we use a UNIX-like (e.g., ext4)—then we must add an extra `chown` command: It is annoying. I suggest to the UNIX developers adding the `uid` option to `mount` for UNIX-like systems, by executing automatically the `chown` command. :)

Answer (score 4):

`uid=1000,gid=1000` options are used when mounting filesystem type that do not use unix scheme for users, such as windows share (know as `cifs`, `smbfs` or samba) or legacy fat (`vfat`).

This allow user 1000 to read, write and delete files.

ext4 (and xfs, brtfs, and many more) use unix ID mapping and do not use these, nor can they change user id on mount options. (root can change owner once filesystem is mounted)

nfs4 allow some kind of mapping (local user 1000 is "onwer" of distant user 1664).